# angular2 define global file path/namespace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I can't figure out how to define a global file path/namespace.

For example, when we want to import an angular2 component, we would do something like

`import { component_name } from '@angular/core'`

and this can be called from any folder nested within the main `app` folder by using the `@angular`.

Is there a way I can define something similar for my root `app` folder such as `@app`, so that I don't have to use `../../../` for deeply nested components?

This would also be useful when the number of feature components gets really high and we want to start referencing sub apps within the root `app` folder.

Comment: I don't think so. The resolution strategy for named module is nodejs and it will look for existence of module in node_modules only. Although you can try absolute path in your case like /app

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this could help you. But you can place an index.ts file on your directory e.g. "directives/index.ts" then from your index.ts file, put export codes somewhat like these

```
export * from "./somename.directive";
export * from "./anothername.directive";
```

Then you could import the modules inside your directive folder like these

```
import {SomeName} from "../directives";
import {AnotherName} from "../directives";
```

instead of this

```
import {SomeName} from "../directives/somename.directive";
import {AnotherName} from "../directives/anothername.directive";
```

I'm not sure with deeply nested components though